# "Transgress the literary/genre fiction divide"

Tags: word-usage, verbs

> "The novel transgresses the literary/genre fiction divide."

Is it proper to say that something transgresses a divide? Is a binary also transgressed? and can we use use the slash punctuation for the binary opposites as in here?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use **transgress**. The word means to sin, to err, to violate, basically to commit a wrong. The novel **bridges** or **crosses** the literary/genre fiction divide would be better, as these are just separate categories of fiction, and the novel is not doing any wrong by combining elements of both.

Comment: Many thanks! very helpful!

Comment: *[Transgress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transgress)* means "to go beyond a boundary or limit" i.e. cross something you're not supposed to cross; this sense isn't found in FeliniusRex's alternatives. You can argue about the author's claims (1) that there's a real divide there and (2) that it's a transgression to cross it (against art, social convention, genre rules, or the Dewey Decimal System), but these debates are outside the scope of EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you wrote is fine. A quick Web search provided some examples:

> . . . it is also problematic because it transgresses the public–private law divide inherent to Swedish law. (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1468-2427.12651)

> . . . a longstanding Mediterranean identity that transgresses the Europe-Africa-divide. (https://www.bigsas-litfestival.com/) (The second hyphen in this example is unusual and unnecessary.)

Those examples use a hyphen, but there is no reason why a slash couldn't also be used to indicate such a division.

Comment: A slash is considered a bit less formal than some alternatives (according to [this blog](https://apvschicago.com/2011/06/slashes-uses-and-restrictions.html) AP frowns upon it). But it's not clear where the original quote is from and if it's a context where it would matter.